# All references are undefined: citations and references to pictures

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib

I am writing a report in LaTeX for the first time and until now everything went fine. But all of a sudden it gives undefined warnings for every reference, no matter if it is to a picture or citation. Even though I have been writing this report for a while now and all references worked fine before.

What I am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{Eel_life.png}
\caption{The life cycle of the European Eel (Figure adapted from 
\citep{Henkel2012}) \label{fig:lifecycle}}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier

The life cycle of the European eel is particularly complex with two 
metamorphoses (see figure \ref{fig:lifecycle}).

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{ReportBibliography}
```

It gives me a warning after defining the figure:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Henkel2012' on page 2 undefined on input line 38
```

And it gives:

```
LaTeX warning: Reference `fig:lifecycle' on page 2 undefined on input line 41.
```

For the reference to the figure.

I have the figure and bibliography file saved in the same folder as the report. I tried running the report file, the bib file, and the report file twice again, but that doesn't help either.

This started when I added two new papers to the .bib file and tried to reference them, but it couldn't find them. I then deleted the files that are created while building the .pdf. When trying to build it afterwards it couldn't find any reference anymore. It also doesn't update any pictures in the report.

I hope it is clear what I am trying to ask and asked correctly, if anything is missing I'll try to add it.

Comment: After deleting the auxiliary files, did you run LaTeX, then re-run BibTeX to rebuild one of the auxiliary files (the `bbl` file), followed by two more LaTeX runs? A separate issue: the `hyperref` package should be loaded last .

Comment: Please explain what you do to "run the bib file". Are you running BibTeX (which, incidentally, shouldn't be run directly on the bib file)?

Comment: By running the bib file I mean closing and opening it again. Is there a specific reason the hyperref should be loaded last? (It doesn't fix this issue)

Comment: Opening,editing, and closing a text file is not usually considered to be a form of "running" that file. You need to perform a BibTeX run. Since you haven't told us much (actually: *anything*) about your computing setup, it's not possible right now to provide specific advice on how you might accomplish this task.

Comment: I actually don't know much about that either, someone else set up the correct programs to work with LaTeX on this computer. I guess it is then easier to ask him, but I'll have to wait a bit then. I hoped it was a silly mistake somewhere that could be fixed  relatively easy, but thanks for thinking about it.

Comment: You should definitely ask the kindly person who set up your TeX distribution for information on how to run BibTeX.

Comment: Turns out I indeed interpreted 'running' wrong. With some googling I found out how to run it. And indeed running it properly solved the problem.  So thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the OP's issue was due to a misunderstanding over the meaning of "running" (BibTeX) and has been solved successfully, according to the comment left by the OP.